# find item in collection with closest date

Tags: c#, datetime, collections

if i have a collection of dates and values.  I want to get the value that is either:

1. Associated to the date in the collection
2. if it doesn't exist, i want a linear interpolation between two points that are around the point i am looking for

ao, here is a simple example. If the collection is:

```
Date   Value  
1/1/2009   100  
1/1/2010   200  
1/1/2011   300
```

if i am looking for  6/1/2010 i would get a value back 250.  i can use any collection if one is better in solving than the other (dictionary, array, etc  ..)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple sorted (on date) list would be sufficient. Just find the last date (let's call it *d1*) that is less or equal than the date you are looking for (let's call that one *d*). The next date *d2* will then be past *d*, assuming there are no duplicate dates.

Now if value *v1* corresponds to *d1* and *v2* corresponds to *d2* then the value you are looking for is *v1* + (*v2* - *v1*) / (*d2* - *d1*) * (*d* - *d1*).

Comment: i wanted to see if there was any faster way of doing it besides a linear search

Comment: There is, as someone here already mentions: if your list is sorted you can do a binary search.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the List type to hold the pairs, Sort them and use List.BinarySearch.

For instance you could have something like the following:

```
struct Pair
{
    public Pair(DateTime t, int v)
    {
        date = t;
        value = v;
    }
    public DateTime date;
    public int value;
}

    ....

    List<Pair> pairs = new List<Pair>();


    pairs.Add(new Pair(DateTime.Now, 100));
    pairs.Add(new Pair(DateTime.Now, 200));

    ....

    // Sort using the time.
    pairs.Sort(delegate(Pair pair1, Pair pair2) {
                           return  pair1.date.CompareTo( pair2.date);
                        }
              );

    // Do binary search.
    int index = pairs.BinarySearch(new Pair(dateToSearch, 0), 
                                   delegate(Pair pair1, Pair pair2) { 
                                       return pair1.date.CompareTo(pair2.date); 
                                   });

    if (index >= 0) {
        // Found the element!
        return pairs[index].value;
    }

    // If not found, List.BinarySearch returns the complement 
    // of the index where the element should have been.
    index = ~index;

    // This date search for is larger than any
    if (index == pairs.Count) {
        //
    }

    // The date searched is smaller than any in the list.
    if (index == 0) {
    }

    // Otherwise return average of elements at index and index-1.
    return (pairs[index-1].value + pairs[index].value)/2;
```

Of course the code is not the best possible, but you get the idea: use List, Sort it and then do BinarySearch.

Lookup MSDN for more information.

List: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx

List.Sort: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3da4abas.aspx

List.BinarySearch: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3f90y839.aspx

Comment: That's an enilightening insight into BinarySearch. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Given a "list of dates" and a "reference date", gets the "closest n numbers". C# code tested.

```
public class ClosestDate
{
    public void GetClosestDate(DateTime referenceDate, 
                                List<DateTime> listDates, int maxResults)
    {
        // final ordered date list
        List<DateTime> finalList = new List<DateTime>();

        DateTime selectedDate = DateTime.MaxValue;

        // loop number of results
        for (int i = 0; i < maxResults; i++)
        {
            // get next closest date
            int tempDistance = int.MaxValue;
            foreach (DateTime currentDate in listDates)
            {
                int currenDistance = this.DateDiff(currentDate, referenceDate);

                if (currenDistance < tempDistance)
                {
                    tempDistance = currenDistance;
                    selectedDate = currentDate;
                }
            }

            // build final list
            finalList.Add(selectedDate);
            // remove element from source list
            listDates.Remove(selectedDate);
        }

        // print results
        foreach (DateTime date in finalList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(date.ToShortDateString());
        }

    }

    private int DateDiff(DateTime Date1, DateTime Date2)
    {
        TimeSpan time = Date1 - Date2;
        return Math.Abs(time.Days);
    }
}
```

Comment: Edited just now. Algorithm tested.

Comment: @TheodoreZographos Was that a specification/requirement? If it works; it works

Answer (score 0):

You can try `SortedDictionary`. Do something like that:

```
int FindInterpolated(DateTime needle)
{
    try
    {
        DateTime lower = haystack.First(key => haystack[key] <= needle);
        DateTime upper = haystack.Last(key => haystack[key] >= needle);
        int v1 = haystack[lower];
        int v2 = haystack[upper];
        long ticksLower = lower.Ticks;
        long ticksUpper = upper.Ticks;
        return (v1 * ticksLower + v2 * ticksUpper) / (ticksLower + ticksUpper);
    }
    catch (InvalidOperationException)
    {
        // thrown if needle is out of range
        // (not between smallest and biggest keys in the haystack)
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: @Vlad - what is container and needle here?

Comment: `needle` is a `DateTime` you are searching for

Comment: Something like that: `SortedDictionary<DateTime, int> haystack = new SortedDictionary<DateTime, int>(); haystack[DateTime.Now] = 5;`